# Javascript looping and object creation

Tags: javascript, arrays, loops, object, prototype

I have the following JSON:

```
[
  {
    "name": "sp5",
    "damage": "68",
    "penetration": "35",
    "class1": "6",
    "class2": "6",
    "class3": "6",
    "class4": "5",
    "class5": "3",
    "class6": "2"
  },
  {
    "name": "sp6",
    "damage": "58",
    "penetration": "43",
    "class1": "6",
    "class2": "6",
    "class3": "6",
    "class4": "6",
    "class5": "5",
    "class6": "4"
  }
]
```

I have a function that loops over the objects in the array and then loops over the properties/keys of that object and attempts to make and push properties damage through class6 of each object to its own new object and onto chart.data.datasets array. I'm getting 16 values in each objects data array instead of the desired 8.

```
function createObjectsForChart(data) {
        console.log(`Data: ${data}`);
        const chart = {
          type: 'bar',
            data: {
                labels: ["Damage", "Penetration", "Class1", "Class 2", "Class 3", "Class 4", "Class 5", "Class 6"],
                datasets: [],
            }
          }
          const dataset = {
            label: "",
            fillColor: "rgba(220,220,220,0.5)",
            strokeColor: "rgba(220,220,220,0.8)",
            highlightFill: "rgba(220,220,220,0.75)",
            highlightStroke: "rgba(220,220,220,1)",
            data: []
          }

          let myChart = Object.create(chart);

          data.forEach((item, i) => {
            console.log(`Item: ${item}, Index: ${i}`);


            console.log(`Data length: ${data.length}`);
            //data[i]

            let myData = Object.create(dataset);
            count = 0;
            for (const property in item) {
              if(count >= 1) {

                //console.log(`Value: ${data[i][property]}`);
                myData.data.push(item[property]);
              }
              console.log(`Property: ${property}, Value: ${item[property]}`);
              count++;
            }
            myData.label = data[i].name;
            myChart.data.datasets.push(myData);
          });






          //myChart.data.datasets[0].highlightStroke = "";
          console.log(myChart.data.datasets);
      }
```

Comment: Can you share expected output as well please!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem here is that you are trying to create deep copy of `dataset` variable using `Object.create`. It does not create deep copy and all copies will share one single instance of `data` array. As a quick dirty fix you can instead use `Object.assign({}, dataset, {data: []})`

Comment: I tried inserting the above suggestion with no success. Can you provide a complete example?

Comment: Just replacing `let myData = Object.create(dataset);` with `let myData = Object.assign({}, dataset, {data: []});` works for me

Comment: @webrocket You are misusing `Object.create` which is used for prototype inheritance rather than make clone of an object.

Comment: It worked! Thanks:) You mentioned that this is the quick and dirty way to fix this. What is the clean and preferred approach?

Comment: @webrocket If your environment supports object spread I would use `const myData = {...dataset, data: []}`. 
Also you should not rely on the "name" property being first when you enumerate object properties, instead of counter compare property value to `'name'` string

Answer (score -1):

```js
var x=[
  {
    "name": "sp5",
    "damage": "68",
    "penetration": "35",
    "class1": "6",
    "class2": "6",'https':'//stackoverflow.com/editing-help',
    "class3": "6",
    "class4": "5",
    "class5": "3",
    "class6": "2"
  },
  {
    "name": "sp6",
    "damage": "58",
    "penetration": "43",
    "class1": "6",
    "class2": "6",
    "class3": "6",
    "class4": "6",
    "class5": "5",
    "class6": "4"
  }
]
createObjectsForChart(x);

function createObjectsForChart(data) {
        console.log(`Data: ${data}`);
        const chart = {
          type: 'bar',
            data: {
                labels: ["Damage", "Penetration", "Class1", "Class 2",
                "Class 3", "Class 4", "Class 5", "Class 6"],
                datasets: [],
            }
          }
          const dataset = {
            label: "",
            fillColor: "rgba(220,220,220,0.5)",
            strokeColor: "rgba(220,220,220,0.8)",
            highlightFill: "rgba(220,220,220,0.75)",
            highlightStroke: "rgba(220,220,220,1)",
            data: []
          }

          let myChart = Object.create(chart);

          data.forEach((item, i) => {
            console.log(`Item: ${item}, Index: ${i}`);


            console.log(`Data length: ${data.length}`);
            //data[i]

          //  let myData = Object.create(dataset);
         let myData =   Object.assign({}, dataset, {data: []})
            count = 0;
            for (const property in item) {
              if(count >= 1) {

                //console.log(`Value: ${data[i][property]}`);
                myData.data.push(item[property]);
              }
              console.log(`Property: ${property}, Value: ${item[property]}`);
              count++;
            }
            myData.label = data[i].name;
            myChart.data.datasets.push(myData);
          });






          //myChart.data.datasets[0].highlightStroke = "";
          console.log(myChart.data.datasets);
      }
```

Comment: Interestingly this comment was added quite some time later than my answer and all it does incorporate suggested by me change in the author source coude.